# How to pass multiple active record object from controller to views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Newbie question

I'm building an employee form, and one of the field in the form is a choice list where the data comes from department.

ActiveRecords: Employee and Department.

I've to pass both the employee and department active records from the controller to the view. How do I pass these multiple active records to the view to create an employee which uses department to build the choice list?

Comment: Why not use an instance variable?

Comment: yep, thats what they're for in controllers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The common Rails approach is just to set the instance variables in your controller action:

#### Approach 1:

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @departments = Department.all
    @employee    = Employee.new
  end

end
```

And in your views:

```
<%= form_for(@employee) do |f| %>

  ...

<% end %>
```

Rails does some magic behind the scenes to expose the controller's instance variables to the view template.

A lot of poeple (myself included) feel that allowing a view template object to access the 
controller's instance variables directly is a violation of object-oriented programming. An object's instance variables should only be accessible to that instance.

#### Approach 2:

The better approach is to wrap these variables in getter methods which are then defined as helper methods:

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController

  # Make these methods available to the view.
  helper_method :departments, :employee

  def new
  end


  # Private - as they're not actions
  private

  def departments
    @departments = Department.all
  end

  def employee
    @employee = Employee.new
  end

end
```

And in your views:

```
<!-- NOTE - no @ sign, it's not an instance variable -->
<%= form_for(employee) do |f| %>

  ...

<% end %>
```

In this case, you're defining a public API for the EmployeeController with two methods, departments and employee, which may be accessed.

Practically, this achieves the first thing as the first example; the difference is mostly academic.

#### Approach 3:

For complex views that need to access a few different variables defined in the controller, you could design your own presenter (or **[facade](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FacadePattern)**) object.

This is probably overkill for your employee form, but to use that as an example:

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController

  # Make these methods available to the view.
  helper_method :employee_form_presenter

  def new
  end


  # Private - as they're not actions
  private

  def employee_form_presenter
    @employee_form_presenter = EmployeeFormPresenter.new(params) # you can pass args from the controller if you need them
  end

end
```

Create a presenter:

```
# in app/presenters/employee_form_presenter.rb
class EmployeeFormPresenter

  attr_reader :employee, :departments

  def initialize(eployee_atts={})
    @employee = Employee.new(eployee_atts)
    @departments = Department.all
  end

end
```

And in your view:

```
<%= form_for(employee_form_presenter.employee) do |f| %>

  ...
  <% for dept in employee_form_presenter.departments do %>

    ...

  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

This keeps your controller really clean and simple - making it easier to test and add extra behaviour to.

All of these approaches work. A presenter is only really required when your controller starts to get more complex. But personally, I 
avoid calling a controller's instance variables from the view as a matter of best-practice.

Comment: Great explanation with multiple approaches, should get more points.

Answer (score 0):

Say your view name is **employee_form.html.erb** then in your controller there should be a method with same name(not necessary).

```
def employee_form
  @employee = Employee.first
  @department = Department.first
end
```

then you can access these instance variables on your **employee_form.html.erb** view like

```
<%= @employee.name %>
<%= @department.name %>
```

etc.